# What is the Java VM type signature for a method returning a generic class type?

Tags: java, java-native-interface

The method is

```
public Set<BluetoothDevice> getBondedDevices ()
```

from Android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter.

I read the type signature guidance [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jni/spec/types.html#wp276), including how to specify an object with L*class-name*; but I don't know how to extend that to a generic class (or even if it is possible).

Comment: Generics do not exist at runtime.

Comment: It returns a `Set`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generics do not exist at runtime; AFAIK, that syntax does not support type parameters.

I'm not sure if that applies to type parameters for base classes (which do exist at runtime in Reflection).

Answer (score 1):

If you are not sure what is the signature of the method, `javap` comes to rescue.

```
import java.util.*;
public class Example {
  public Set<Float> getSet() {
    return null;
  }
}
```

you can easily check the signature following way

```
> javac Example.java
> javap -s -cp . Example
Compiled from "Example.java"
public class Example {
  public Example();
    descriptor: ()V

  public java.util.Set<java.lang.Float> getSet();
    descriptor: ()Ljava/util/Set;
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  I discovered that javap is included in microsoft_dist_openjdk_1.8.0.25\bin.

Answer (score 0):

You are asking about Type Erasure in java. Your answer is Object. If you have:

```
List<E> myList;
```

The compiler will interpret E as Object. This case is known as Class Type Erasure. There is also a case called Method Type Erasure.